# How to apply animated transforms to these SVG elements in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, transform

I have an `<a>` tag that contains an SVG and which - when clicked - toggles an "open" class on the `<header>`. Depending on whether the "open" class is present, different transforms are applied to child elements of the SVG.

This all works fine everywhere I've tested it, apart from IE 9-11.

These are the SCSS transforms I've tried using:

```
svg {
    .cross1 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
        -ms-transform-origin: 8px 1px 0;
            transform-origin: 8px 1px 0;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
           -moz-transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
             -o-transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
                transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
    }
}

.open svg {
    .cross1 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform-origin: 8px 1px 0;
            transform-origin: 8px 1px 0;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
           -moz-transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
             -o-transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
                transition: transform 0.25s, cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
    }
}
```

And see the full fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdxjrzqg/).

Could somebody enlighten me as to how to get these working on IE9+ ?

Comment: I don't think IE implements this for SVG elements. You could write your own javascript shim I suppose but that would be a significant project.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the case. (Almost) unbelievable. Tried a new approach and thankfully you can transform pseudo elements in IE - although it seems you can't animate them.